# Noob Question : Need help to understand : Probability with Martingales : page 24

Tags: measure-theory

Coin toss infinitely often.

The sample space is $\Omega = \{ H , T \}^{\mathbb{N}} $
And we do not have any problem.
And a typical point is $\omega = \omega_1 \omega_2 \omega_3 ... $ where $\omega_n \in \{ H, T\} $ and still understandable.

Now, 
$$
\mathcal{F} =  \sigma ( \{ \omega \in \Omega : \omega_n = W \} : n \in \mathbb{N} , W \in \{ H, T\}) 
$$ 
Still, not a problem.
Now - apparently $\mathcal{F} \ne \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ why?
Is that because  $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ is actually $\mathbb{R}$ ?

My notion of limits and tending to limits are going for a toss.
Please help.

Comment: I don't understand your definition of $\mathcal{F}$. Which sets are generating the $\sigma$-field? Is it all the singletons $\{\omega\}$ such that $\omega \in \Omega$?

Comment: Fixed it - now copied letter by letter from *the book*.

Comment: "The book" = Williams' PWM?

Comment: Indeed Did. That is good alliteration!